# jquery array and display with custom format

Tags: jquery

I have an object similar :

```
{
a:{'1':'Blue','2':'Red'},
b:{'1':'Large','2':'Small'}
}
```

I want my array to be displayed using jQuery as shown below :

Blue / Large

Blue / Small

Red / Large

Red / Small

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Would you mind adding your attemps to get the desired results ? Please

Answer (score 0):

With two loop you can achieve this,

```js
let obj = {
a:{'1':'Blue','2':'Red'},
b:{'1':'Large','2':'Small'}
}

const result = document.getElementById("result")

for(let i in obj['a'])
  for(let j in obj['b'])
    result.innerHTML += `<h4>${obj['a'][i]} - ${obj['b'][j]}</h4>`
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My object has dynamic rows and columns:

```
{
1:{1:'Blue',2:'Red',3:'Green'},
2:{1:'S',2:'M',3:'L',4:'XL'},
3:{1:'Guarantee One',2:'Guarantee Two'},
}
```

So the result will be dynamic :

Blue / S / Guarantee One

Blue / S / Guarantee Two

Blue / M / Guarantee One

Blue / M /  Guarantee Two

Blue / L / Guarantee One

Blue / L / Guarantee Two

Blue / XL / Guarantee One

Blue / XL / Guarantee Two

Red / S / Guarantee One

Red / S / Guarantee Two

Red / ...